# How to implement pagination in Android listview

Tags: android, listview, navigation

I am working for Android app, in which I need to show listview with items. But There are more elements to show in listview.

I decided to implement pagination . I tried searching in Google but does not find any related information.

Can anybody help me please..

Comment: what kind of navigation? you can simply create a activity after list item click

Comment: sorry for my mistake.please check the edited question..

Comment: CommonWare's [`EndlessAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless) is a commonly used approach for paginating lists. Alternatively, you could implement the pagination logic yourself, or use e.g. buttons to go from one page to the next.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Implementing pagination is very simple.

Take look at this...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {  

    private ListView listview;
    private TextView title;

   private ArrayList<String> data;
    ArrayAdapter<String> sd;


    public int TOTAL_LIST_ITEMS = 1030;
    public int NUM_ITEMS_PAGE   = 100;
    private int noOfBtns;
    private Button[] btns;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        title    = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);

        Btnfooter();

        data = new ArrayList<String>();

        /*
         * The ArrayList data contains all the list items
         */
        for(int i=0;i<TOTAL_LIST_ITEMS;i++)
        {
            data.add("This is Item "+(i+1));
        }

        loadList(0);

        CheckBtnBackGroud(0);

    }

    private void Btnfooter()
    {
        int val = TOTAL_LIST_ITEMS%NUM_ITEMS_PAGE;
        val = val==0?0:1;
        noOfBtns=TOTAL_LIST_ITEMS/NUM_ITEMS_PAGE+val;

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.btnLay);

        btns = new Button[noOfBtns];

        for(int i=0;i<noOfBtns;i++)
        {
            btns[i] =   new Button(this);
            btns[i].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
            btns[i].setText(""+(i+1));

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new     LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            ll.addView(btns[i], lp);

            final int j = i;
            btns[j].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    loadList(j);
                    CheckBtnBackGroud(j);
                }
            });
        }

    }

    /**
     * Method for Checking Button Backgrounds
     */
    private void CheckBtnBackGroud(int index)
    {
        title.setText("Page "+(index+1)+" of "+noOfBtns);
        for(int i=0;i<noOfBtns;i++)
        {
            if(i==index)
            {
                btns[index].setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.box_green));
                btns[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
            }
            else
            {
                btns[i].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
                btns[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Method for loading data in listview
     * @param number
     */
    private void loadList(int number)
    {
        ArrayList<String> sort = new ArrayList<String>();

        int start = number * NUM_ITEMS_PAGE;
        for(int i=start;i<(start)+NUM_ITEMS_PAGE;i++)
        {
            if(i<data.size())
            {
                sort.add(data.get(i));
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        sd = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                sort);
        listview.setAdapter(sd);
    }
}
```

**Xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:padding="10dp"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:divider="#000"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fadingEdge="none"/>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnLay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

For more clear explanation and source code visit this links

[ListView Pagination Ex-1](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2013/05/20/listview-pagination-ex-1/)

[ListView Pagination Ex-2](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2013/05/20/listview-pagination-ex-2/)

Answer (score 2):

I have created this custom listview.

```
    package com.pixecon.custom.views;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class PagingListView extends ListView {
    boolean needScroll = true;
    private String TAG = "CustomListView";

    public PagingListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setNeedScroll(boolean needScroll) {
        this.needScroll = needScroll;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (!needScroll) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener l) {
        super.setOnScrollListener(l);
    }

    public void onScrollStarted() {
        //Scroll Started.
    }

    public void onScrollStopped() {
        centralizeTheView();
    }

    private void centralizeTheView() {
        int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        int centerY = height / 2;

        int visibleFirstItemPosition = getFirstVisiblePosition();
        int visibleLastItemPosition = getLastVisiblePosition();

        Log.d(TAG, "visibleFirstVisible = " + visibleFirstItemPosition);
        Log.d(TAG, "visibleLastVisible = " + visibleLastItemPosition);

        //TODO: Check the calcualted value and reconfirm.
        int firstPositionInGroup = visibleFirstItemPosition % 2 - 1;
        if (firstPositionInGroup < 0) {
            firstPositionInGroup = 0;
        }

        FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) getChildAt(firstPositionInGroup);
        int bottom = layout.getBottom();

        //Calculate the exact bottom of the view by subtracting
        if (bottom > centerY) {
            Log.d(TAG, "First Item - " + visibleFirstItemPosition);
            /*listView.smoothScrollBy(3, 1);*/
            //listView.smoothScrollToPosition(visibleFirstItemPosition);
            setSelection(visibleFirstItemPosition);
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Last Item - " + visibleLastItemPosition);
            /*listView.smoothScrollBy(-3, 1);*/
            //listView.smoothScrollToPosition(visibleLastItemPosition);
            setSelection(visibleLastItemPosition);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You forgot to mantion that ScrollListener should be implemented to handle  scroll change states and to call onScrollStoped.