# web service returns 10000 rows of data, how to handle this

Tags: android, web-services

this is obviously too much data to display in an android app.. what can i do to mitigate this problem ?

I tried to show all 10000 rows in a list view but i got poor performance. I also tried to display all 10000 rows of data in the list view but that just made it slow

Comment: use PageNation added and handle with scrollistnear in android

Comment: do you think user realy need all of those data? you can use pagination to reduce amount of data u receive from server

Comment: I think this is what you need
Pagination


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661662/how-to-implement-pagination-in-android-listview/16661802#16661802

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need that method ? WS method's approach is wrong. First of all, you must change method signature like this `(int pageNumber, int recordNumber )` and make pagination enabled. If you use a listview, you can show the first 10 record. Then, if the user need more than that, could click to show more button.