# how to use pagination in Android ListView while fetching SQLite data?

Tags: android

I want to implement populate ListView from SQLite database. But i have lot of records in my SQLite database.Almost 2000 records are there in SQLite database.So I'm going to implement pagination with ListView scrolling. First I want to display 50 records and after that whenever I scroll the ListView then again display the next 50 records in ListView. Can someone help me. How to implement this.

Comment: no pagination needed at all: i have a table with 50000 rows and it just works ok, one thing: use a `[Simple]CursorAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

Look this post [How to implement pagination in Android listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661662/how-to-implement-pagination-in-android-listview) may help for you problem. And ListView **doesn`t** do it by itself be sure ... you need to implement pagination because if you load 4000 records at one time your app will crash eventualy you are on the right way!
Hope to help!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i want to do only one button.

Comment: `you need to implement pagination because if you load 4000 records` i dont agree, just use `[Simple]CursorAdapter` and you can see 100k row tables with no trouble

Comment: hmm i didnt know and you load all 100k records at one time without any problem ?

Comment: with no problem at all, just use `SCA`

Comment: ok i didnt know really , i will do little research how it works ;) thanks for the advice!