# Android Loading List view From URL Json Without waiting

Tags: android, json, listview, asynchronous

I want to Load JSON data from URL into ListView as soon as user open the Activity without Showing ProgressBar and Loading Message. When user scroll the ListView more data should be loaded on Scrolling.
I tried Asynck Task but My URL is giving large JSON at once. In facebook,gmail and in other shopping and News applications List Items are loading as soon as i open App.

Example App for List Loading : 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eterno

Comment: you might have to consider implementing  pagination for your listview,these links can be helpful  http://www.androidhub4you.com/2014/03/android-pagination-example-dynamic.html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661662/how-to-implement-pagination-in-android-listview

Comment: your backend has to support pagination, so you can ask it to give you let's say first 20 items, then to give you 20 items starting from position 21, and so on.