# ListView, API calls and onScrollListener

Tags: java, android, api, listview, adapter

I'm developing an Android app for an online blog that retrieves data from its API (the company made it so I could use it in it, so it can be modified).

The app shows a ListView with **n** blog entries on load. The thing is I've spent the last three days searching for a way to add a Previous/Next button at the bottom of said ListView, just to finally give up and try another way.

I've seen apps update and append contents pulled from a server to a list (not sure which type) while the user scrolls up and down on it.

Is this possible? If so, how can it be done?

Any revealing piece of information, example (as simple as it may be) or help would be much appreciated!

**EXTRA INFO**

I'm loading the ListView in a LinearLineout, which is called in the onCreate method.

**content_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.company.myApp.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/myGrey"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I also use a custom adapter to fill the ListView with the data retrieved. This data is retrieved by a custom class and stored in a List and that list is then passed as a parameter to the method I use to set such adapter.

```
public class AdaptadorPosts extends ArrayAdapter {
    public AdaptadorPosts(Context context, List objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = convertView;

        if (null == convertView) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_posts, parent, false);
        }

        TextView titulo = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
        TextView resumen = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.resumen);
        TextView fecha = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.fecha);
        TextView autor = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.autor);

        Post item = (Post) getItem(position);

        titulo.setText(Html.fromHtml(item.getTitulo()));
        if(item.getResumen().isEmpty() || item.getResumen().equals(null)) {
            resumen.setText("¡No hay resumen!");
        } else {
            resumen.setText(Html.fromHtml(item.getResumen()));
        }
        fecha.setText(Html.fromHtml(item.getFecha()));
        autor.setText(Html.fromHtml(item.getAutor().getNombre()));

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: this thing is called lazy loading here is example http://blogs.innovationm.com/lazy-loading-and-memory-management-of-images-in-listview-in-android/

Comment: This is called pagination https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661662/how-to-implement-pagination-in-android-listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to:

1. Add a Prev/Next button on the bottom of your screen
2. You have endless content which you want to show dynamically

The first can be easily achieved by using [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) and for the second you should use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html).

For your layout you can use something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/light_gray">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/lv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_prev"/>

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_next"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want your buttons to be directly below the list, you can attach them by using `android:layout_below="@id/lv"` and removing `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

The Android RecyclerView displays a given number of items (e.x. 10) and preloads some of the next and previous items. It's ideal for endless lists. If you want to add items to it dynamically, you need to do that in the adapter by adding the item to the list and calling the `notifyItemInserted(int position)` method.

Comment: Thank you! I know it's been a long time since I asked the question, but I actually forgot I had an account here!